# UITableViewCell - How to set selection clipping?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

In my app, I have a UITableView and each UITableViewCell utilizes a custom background and style with the following code in the "WillDisplayCell" method:

```
UIImage *cellBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableView_Cell_Background_iPhone"];

UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellBackgroundImage     highlightedImage:cellBackgroundImage];

[cell setBackgroundView:backgroundImage];

[backgroundImage release];
```

The problem is that the PNG I'm using as the background is a rectangle, but the UITableViewCell is a rounded rectangle with a specific layer radius property. When I select a cell, the background overrides the rounded nature of the cell and I get a jarring blue highlighted sharp rectangle. Is there a way to set the selected state corner radius or something along those lines? My only other option if not would be to create a PNG background that fits the rounded rectangle perfectly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would set the [selectionStyle](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/selectionStyle) of the cell to UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone, this stops the blue highlight.  Then start to do a custom selection job.

You will have to make a custom subclass of UITalbeViewCell.  Override setSelected or if that doesn't work user a gesture recognizer or override touchesBegan etc.  I have done it once, before, I forget exactly how, if you have trouble let me know and ill look it up.

When you detect that the cell is selected, perhaps create a translucent overlay as a PNG and make it appear when the cell is selected.  Alternatively lower the transparency of the background image or add a color mask.